# Find a function that satisfies the following properties.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a function $f:[0,\infty] \to [0,\infty]$ such that is strictly increasing, bounded, and $\forall x,y \in [0,+\infty],f(x+y) \leqslant f(x) +f(y)$. I am thinking about $1-e^{-x}$, but does the last property hold? If holds, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe $$\frac{x}{1+x}$$ will do?

Your problem just reminds me of defining a new metric $d':=\frac{d}{1+d}$ out of the old one $d$.

Comment: Yes, I am actually working on a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try $$\arctan(x)$$ For the final property, use the sum formula for tangent.